# Executable Jar Could not find stylesheet

Tags: java, javafx

Problem:
I am using an external Biblithok from jFonix. The library is also inserted in the BuildPath .

Within Eclipse the program runs 100%.

When executing an executable jar, the error comes:

```
Could not find stylesheet: Jar: file: / path .....
```

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.show();
```

Error cmd:

```
java -jar test.jar
Feb 08, 2019 12:00:23 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not find stylesheet: jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test.jar!/bin/application/application.css
```

Strucure:
projektname

```
 -src-Folder
    -application-package
        - Main.java
        - Controller.java
        - application.css
        - GUI.fxml
-img-Folder
    - images.png
-Referenced Libraires 
    - jfonenix.jar
        - many packages
        - css.controls
            - many .css
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNHPW.png)

Comment: We need more information what does your project structure look like? Do you have your css in any folders this may affect what you need to put in your getResources.

Comment: Is your stylesheet folder marked as "sourcefolder"?

Comment: Structure are added. I havent a stylesheet-Folder, But i use a css.sheet from the referenced Libraries

Comment: Can someone help me?